# Ui not updating for events outside ngZone Angular

Tags: angular, api, contacts, ngzone

In my project I am fetching email via Google Contact API. My problem is that After fetching email, angular UI is not updating.

Here is my code for the fetching emails in ContactComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ContactService } from './contacts.service';
import { Contact } from './contact.model';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { ContactListComponent } from './contact-list/contact-list.component';
declare var gapi: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacts',
  templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css'],
  providers: [ContactService]
})
export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private contactService: ContactService) {}
  authConfig: any;
  contactsList: Contact[] = [];
  ContactsFound = true;
  ngOnInit() {

    this.ContactsFound = false;

    this.authConfig = {
      client_id:
        '<my_client_id>',
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly'
    };

  }

  fetchGoogleContacts() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey('<my_key>');
    gapi.auth2.authorize(this.authConfig, this.handleAuthorization);
  }

  handleAuthorization = authorizationResult => {
    if (authorizationResult && !authorizationResult.error) {
      const url: string =
        'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin?' +
        'alt=json&max-results=500&v=3.0&access_token=' +
        authorizationResult.access_token;
      console.log('Authorization success, URL: ', url);
      this.http.get<any>(url).subscribe(response => {
        if (response.feed && response.feed.entry) {
          // console.log(response.feed.entry);
          this.saveContacts(response.feed.entry);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  saveContacts(ContactEntry) {

    this.contactsList = [];

    ContactEntry.forEach((entry) => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
      let contact: Contact = { email: '', name: '' };

      if (entry.gd$name !== undefined) {
        contact.name = entry.gd$name.gd$fullName.$t;
        // console.log('Name of contact: ' + contact.name);
      }

      if (Array.isArray(entry.gd$email)) {
        entry.gd$email.forEach((emailEntry) => {
          if (emailEntry.address !== undefined) {
           // console.log('Email of contact: ' + emailEntry.address);
            contact.email = emailEntry.address;
          }
        });
      }

      this.contactsList.push(contact);
    });

    this.ContactsFound = true;
     // Calling next in ContactService for propagating the events
    this.contactService.contactsArrived(this.contactsList);
    console.log(`Contacts List Length ${this.contactsList.length}`);

  }



}
```

I am using service for subscribing to event for adding emails

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Contact } from './contact.model';
import {  BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { TouchSequence } from 'selenium-webdriver';



@Injectable()
export class ContactService {
  contacts: Contact[] = [];
  private contactsSubject = new Subject<Contact[]>();
  contactArrived$ = this.contactsSubject.asObservable();

  constructor() {
  }

  contactsArrived(contacts: Contact[]) {
     console.log(`Contacts Arrived in Contact Service`);
     if (contacts) {
        this.contactsSubject.next(contacts);
     }
  }
}
```

Here is my contact.component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="fetchGoogleContacts()">Import Contacts</button>
<app-contact-list [contacts]="contactsList"></app-contact-list>
```

Code for Contact-List Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnDestroy, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactService } from '../contacts.service';

import { Contact } from '../contact.model';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-list',
  templateUrl: './contact-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-list.component.css']
})
export class ContactListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() contacts: Contact[];
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private contactService: ContactService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.contactService.contactArrived$.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.contacts = data;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }


}
```

ContactList Component.html

```
<div>
  <div>
    <br>
    <h4 class="card-title">Your Contacts</h4>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">Contact Names
        <span class="float-right">Emails Ids</span>
      </div>
      <ul *ngFor="let contact of contacts" class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <app-contact-item [contact]="contact"></app-contact-item>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am getting data in the Contact-List Component after the rest call from the google contact API. But sum how my UI is not updating. List is not getting updated. After googling I came to know Angular behave differently for the events outside the ngZone. How can I update the UI after I receive the data.

Comment: what is the purpose of passing a list through an input property if you are going to set it inside of the child component through a subscribe callback anyway?

Answer (score -1):

### Root cause

It looks like the `contacts` is not being capture as a part of change detector mechanism of Angular.

### Fix : You have couple of choices

> The first is to have setter and getter for the `contacts`

`Functions` always play the vital role as part of change detector so it ensure that changes are in effect and UI is updated accordingly.

### in ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnDestroy, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactService } from '../contacts.service';

import { Contact } from '../contact.model';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-list',
  templateUrl: './contact-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-list.component.css']
})
export class ContactListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input("contacts") _contacts: Contact[];
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private contactService: ContactService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.contactService.contactArrived$.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this._contacts = data;
    });
  }

    get contacts(){
        return this._contacts;
    }

    set contacts(contacts){
        this._contacts = contacts;
    }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

> The second option to have use setTimeout while setting the contacts

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.contactService.contactArrived$.subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data);
          setTimeout(()=>this.contacts = data);
        });
      }
```

Comment: Your first approach will have no effect, and the second is IMO a hack.

Comment: Would you please let me know why would the first approach will not work and what would be the alternative for this ?

Comment: After adding the getters and setters Ui was not updating. But after using Ngzone run method, UI is updating.  
```ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.contactService.contactArrived$.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this._ngzone.run(() => {
        this._contacts = data;
      });
    });
  }```